# How to draw a table with different braces

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, braces, implicit-braces

I do not have any idea how to draw this kind of braces in a table! (picture attached)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If the problem are only braces, please provide small but complete document with your table without braces. It seems that `nicematrix` package can help you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... `multirow.sty` will helps you....

Comment: Many thanks,
It does not work for me.
I should add nicematrix file for my latex.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You need the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5-10 of 2021-02-05).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lccwc{2cm}ccc}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
\toprule
\Block{1-2}{Particle} & & Spin & & \Block{1-2}{Super-particle} & & Spin\\
\midrule
Quark & q & $\frac12$ & & Squark & $\tilde{\text{q}}_L$, $\tilde{\text{q}}_R$ & $0$ \\
Lepton & $\ell^{\pm}$ & $\frac12$ & & Slepton & $\tilde{\ell}_L^{\pm}$, $\tilde{\ell}_R^{\pm}$ & $0$\\
Neutrino & $\nu$ & $\frac12$ & & Sneutrino &  $\tilde{\nu}_L$, $\tilde{\nu}_R$ (?) & $0$\\
Gluon & g & $1$ & & Gluino &  $\tilde{\text{g}}$ & $\frac12$\\
Photon & $\gamma$ & $1$ & $\tilde{\gamma}$ & \Block{3-1}{Neutralino} & \Block{3-1}{$\tilde{\chi}_1^0$,
  $\tilde{\chi}_3^0$, $\tilde{\chi}_3^0$, $\tilde{\chi}_4^0$} & \Block{3-1}{$\frac12$}\\
Z boson & Z & $1$  & $\tilde{\text{Z}}$ &  \\
\Block{2-1}{Higgs} & \Block{2-1}{H}  & \Block{2-1}{$0$} & $\tilde{\text{H}}_1^0$, $\tilde{\text{H}}_2^0$ \\
& & & $\tilde{\text{H}}^{\pm}$ & \Block{2-1}{Chargino} & \Block{2-1}{$\tilde{\chi}_1^{\pm}$,
  $\tilde{\chi}_2^{\pm}$} & \Block{2-1}{$\frac12$}\\
W boson & W$^{\pm}$ & $1$ & $\tilde{\text{W}}^{\pm}$ \\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix{\{}{8-4}{9-4}{.}[left-xshift=2mm]
\SubMatrix{.}{6-4}{8-4}{\}}[right-xshift=2mm]
\SubMatrix{.}{9-4}{10-4}{\}}[right-xshift=2mm]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: +1! However, OP should first provide code for her/his table, as I ask him :-). BTW,why is not column with math expression in "math" mode with specifying this column as `>{$ }c<{$}`?

Comment: @Zarko: For the column in math mode, I usually put the `$` in each cell in order to have the syntatic color for math mode of my LaTeX editor in each cell.

Comment: Great thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

A solution with `makecell, multirow` and  `bigdelim`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{>{$}c<{$}}*{3}{c}l*{2}{>{$}c<{$}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Particle} & \text{Spin} & & & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Super-particle}& \text{Spin}\\
\midrule
Quark & \mathrm q & \frac12 & & & & Squark & \tilde{\mathrm{q}}_L, \tilde{\mathrm{q}}_R & 0 \\
 Lepton & \ell^{\pm} & \frac12 & & & & Slepton & \tilde{\ell}_L^{\pm}, \tilde{\ell}_R^{\pm} & 0 \\
Neutrino & \upnu & \frac12 & & & & Sneutrino & \tilde{\upnu}_L, \tilde{\upnu}_R \:(?) & 0 \\
Gluon & \mathrm g & 1 & & & & Gluino & \tilde{\mathrm g } & \frac12 \\
Photon & \upgamma & 1 & & $ \tilde{\gamma} $\\
Z boson & \mathrm Z &1 & &$ \tilde{\mathrm Z} $ & & Neutralino & \tilde{\upchi}_1^0, \tilde{\upchi}_3^0, \tilde{\upchi}_3^0, \tilde{\upchi}_4^0 & \frac12\\
\multirow{2}{*}{Higgs} & \multirowcell{2}{\mathrm H} & \multirowcell{2}{0} & \ldelim\{{2}{*}& $\tilde{\mathrm H}_1^0, \tilde{\mathrm H}_2^0$ & \rdelim\}{-3}{*} \\[0.5ex]
 & & & & $\tilde{\mathrm H}^{\pm}$ & \rdelim\}{2}{*}\\
W boson & \mathrm W^{\pm} & 1 & & $\tilde{\mathrm W }^{\pm}$ & &\multirow{-2}{*}{Chargino} & \multirowcell{-2}{\tilde{\upchi}_1^{\pm}, \tilde{\upchi}_2^{\pm}}& \multirowcell{-2}{\frac12}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `\smash` and using OpTeX:

```
\thistable={\tabstrut={\lower4pt\vbox to15pt{}}}
\table{l 5c lcc}{
  Quark & q & $1\over2$ &&&& Squark & $\tilde{\rm q}_L$, $\tilde{\rm q}_R$ & 0 \crl
  Lepton & $\ell^\pm$ & $1\over2$ &&&& Slepton & $\tilde\ell_L^\pm$, $\tilde\ell_R^\pm$ & 0 \cr
  Neutrino & $\nu$ & $1\over2$ &&&& Sneutrino &  $\tilde\nu_L$, $\tilde\nu_R$ (?) & 0 \cr
  Gluon & g & 1 &&&& Gluino &  $\tilde{\rm g}$ & $1\over2$ \cr
  Photon & $\gamma$ & 1 & & $\tilde\gamma$ \cr
  Z boson & Z & 1 && $\tilde{\rm Z}$ & $\smash{\left.\vbox to20pt{}\right\}}$ & Neutralino & 
    $\tilde\chi_1^0$, $\tilde\chi_3^0$, $\tilde\chi_3^0$, $\tilde\chi_4^0$ & $1\over2$ \cr
  \vspan2{Higgs} & \vspan2{H}  & \vspan2{0} & \vspan2{$\biggl\{$} & $\tilde{\rm H}_1^0$, $\tilde{\rm H}_2^0$ \cr
    &&&& $\tilde{\rm H}^\pm$ & \vspan2{$\smash{\biggl\}}$} & \vspan2{Chargino} & 
    \vspan2{$\tilde\chi_1^\pm$, $\tilde\chi_2^\pm$} & \vspan2{$1\over2$} \cr
  W boson & W$^\pm$ & 1 && $\tilde{\rm W}^\pm$ \cr
}
\bye
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody!
The table is exactly the same as what I want.

But I am still challenging with  nicematrix package. I have copy the newest nicematrix.sty file into my latex directory. But there are lots of errors. And the other problem is the run doesn't stop!!

Can anybody help me through these problems?

--
Errors in nicematrix.sty file:

Undefined control sequence. \ProvideDocumentCommand
Missing \begin{document}. $
Undefined control sequence. \regex_const:Nn
...

Comment: Would you please let me know which other packages you used beside the `pst-optexp` ?
I also have lots of problems with your code. Maybe these because I use an old texlive version.

Comment: I don't use any LaTeX packages because I don't use LaTeX. I am sorry if you are confused. OpTeX is another way to use TeX, different from LaTeX. Becuase LaTeX was not mentioned explicitly in the question and there is no MWE, I give no-LaTeX solution here. If you have old texlive distribution then OpTeX is missing here. But you can inspire by the main idea of my answer (which is independent of used packages or TeX-format): to use `\smash{\Biggl\{}` for the brackets.

Comment: Dear Wipet,

Thanks for your prompt answer and complete explanation. Anyway it could be useful for me and also maybe for the athers.